# Jenkins agent for connecting Amazone EKS not work

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I try to configure Kubernetes agent in my Jenkins for deploy microservices using Jenkins pipeline.
I created Amazone EKS cluster using eksctl commande. After cluster creation a created kubeconfig file for configure secret file credential in Jenkins.

When i try to connect my kubernetes agent to my cluster I have an error :

```
Error testing connection https://<CLUSTER>.sk1.eu-west-3.eks.amazonaws.com: Failure executing: GET at: https://<CLUSTER>.sk1.eu-west-3.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default". Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=403, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=pods, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default", metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Forbidden, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config` secret does not have enough permission to perform basic task. Please bind the below role in your service account who's token you have used in config secret. Please follow this one

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: jenkins-master
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["events"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins-master
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins-master
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins-master //replace your service account name
```

For more details follow this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/quick-and-simple-how-to-setup-jenkins-distributed-master-slave-build-on-kubernetes-37f3d76aae7d).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Should I install Jenkins on my Kubernetes cluster ? I want to use a Jenkins installed on another machine

Comment: Jenkins can be installed anywhere as long as its reachable from