# Jenkins pipeline k8s deployment failed

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy my application into EKS cluster. When I am running jenkins job I could able to get `kubectl get pod` details with running state at the same time when I'm trying to deploy yaml file via jenkins I'm getting below error:

```
+ kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "deployment.yaml": deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:node:ip-10-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal" cannot create resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"
```

create pod

```
+ kubectl '--kubeconfig=****' '--context=arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:123456789101:cluster/my-cluster' sh "kubectl auth can-i list pods"
yes
```

Create deployment

```
+ kubectl '--kubeconfig=****' '--context=arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:123456789101:cluster/my-cluster' sh "kubectl auth can-i create deployment"
no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that means you have permissions to read/list pods data but dont have an access for creating `deployment` object.

Below is 2 examples, check and compare them.

- 1st is just reading rules(what you currently have)

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Pod
  # objects is "pods"
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

- 2nd is permissions for deployment creation (`verbs: ["**create**"]`). Most probably you miss this part

```
rules:
- apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Deployment
  # objects is "deployments"
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

For more options, examples and explanations please check [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

Comment: Hi Vit, thanks for helping. I'm new to the k8 world, could you please tell me how to see above rules which you asked me to check, what command i need to use it.

Comment: could you please help me

Comment: check please reply in  [Jenkins agent for connecting Amazone EKS not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67048136/9929015), it should clarify you a lot

Comment: Check your Roles, RoleBinding. ANd please check [Set up Jenkins in a Kubernetes cluster](https://medium.com/swlh/set-up-jenkins-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-96660c8d9ab) - I used this article when played with jenkins and EKS.  Especially **Adding RBAC Authorization** part

Comment: hard to suggest without understanding how you installed cluster, etc.

Comment: See i meant to say i have many roles and role binding the thing is i don't have specific service account for jenkins

Comment: `User "system:node:ip-10-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal" cannot create resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"` check please  roles and bindings for  user from your error.